# How to fill data into HTML table cell of each row from excel using vba selenium

Tags: excel, vba, selenium-webdriver

[this tr is is the tagname of each row and td is cell of each row. Here I want fill data from excel into td(6) cell of first row then go to next as same way but I couldn't.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c44VA.jpg)

```
Set tb = driver.FindElementByCss("html body div.mainDiv div.dashboard_div div.fixDiv form#frmBidSubmit table tbody tr td.contentArea_1 div.t_space table.formStyle_1 tbody tr td div table#FormMatrix.tableList_1")

For Each Row In tb.FindElementsByTag("tr")
    For Each cel In Row.FindElementsByTag("td").Item(6)
        cel.Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range(r, y).Value
    Next cel
    y = 0
    r = r + 1
Next Row
```

the above could I try but didn't success yet. Please provide me the correction where I need to do.

Comment: _y_ cannot be zero as this is an invalid column reference, You also will want a shorter css selector if possible.

Comment: Please don't post images of html/links to images. Use the snippet tool via [edit] to insert html such that people can use it for testing. And the url here would be useful.

Comment: import time
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Ie()
driver.set_page_load_timeout(10)
driver.get("https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/")

driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_class_name("demo-frame"))
driver.find_element_by_id("datepicker").click()

month = "December-2019"
set_month = month.split("-")

while driver.find_element_by_class_name("ui-datepicker-title").text != set_month:
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("a[data-handler='next']").click()

driver_find_element_by_xpath("//table//a[text()='10']").click()
time.sleep(2)

Comment: By above code I didn't click 10 December 2019. It just click next and move on. Please help me where I need to do correction.

Comment: Hi, use [edit] to add your code to the question itself. Paste the code in the question and highlight the code only and press ctrl + k to format